# Htaccess parameter rewrite and redirection

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

How do I rewrite this?

somepage.php?parameter1=value1&parameter2=value2&parameter3=value3 to 
somepage/parameter1/value1/parameter2/value2/parameter3/value3

and also redirect to that for older indexed URLs.

Also, I want it to work for only two of those parameters, or one, or none.
I've tried this, but doesn't seem to work that well:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/parameter1/([^/]*)$ $1.php?lang=$2 [PT]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this generic rule to rewrite `/somepage/n1/v1/n2/v2` to `/somepage.php?n2=v2&n1=v1`

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,NE,L]

RewriteRule ^(somepage)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)(/.*)?$ /$1/$4?$2=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^(somepage)/?$ $1.php [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: That's not true, I have even tested it with `http://localhost/somepage/n1/v1/n2/v2/n3/v3/n4/v4/` and it works.

Comment: I shall try it myself too since I always though you had to define every case manually (as in my answer below). I'm intrigued by your answer. What exactly is happening here? Because I only see 3 fieldsm but you use up to $4. And how does it know how to apply the extra parameters you didn't define in the htaccess. Is it because of the QSA flag? Haven't seen that before.

Comment: There are indeed 4 capturing groups. I think you din't notice `(somepage)` as first one. And this rule is recursive. As long as there is a `/name/value` in URL it will keep rewriting that to `?name=value`  and `QSA` will make sure to append it to existing query parameters.

Comment: Oh wow, that is extremely powerful. So you rewrite the first parameter as a querystring, then add the part behind it back in front, and it goes through the process all over again until all parameters have been processed. If I understood correctly. 

So http://localhost/somepage/n1/v1/n2/v2/n3/v3/n4/v4/ will be rewritten to http://localhost/somepage.php?n4=v4&n3=v3&n2=v2&n1=v1 right?

Thanks for the tip! I can't believe I haven't encountered this before. +100 ;)

Comment: Yes that's exactly how it is converting to query string and that's the whole purpose of putting `/$4`  right after `$1`

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create a rule for each possible situation, with 2 parameters, 1 parameter and no parameters.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/parameter1/([^/]*)/parameter2/([^/]*)(/?)$ $1.php?
parameter1=$2&parameter2=$3 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/parameter1/([^/]*)(/?)$ $1.php?parameter1=$2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)(/?)$ $1.php [NC]
```

The (/?) at the end is to also catch the situations where the link ends with a possible slash.